# Running a local CGI webserver on iOS

Tags: ios, webserver, cgi

I am looking for a way to run a local webserver on an iPhone/iPad which can serve dynamic content through CGI. I found some http servers, like [CocoaHTTPServer](https://github.com/robbiehanson/CocoaHTTPServer) and [GCDWebServer](https://github.com/swisspol/GCDWebServer), but they don't support CGI.
There seems to be a way when jailbreaking your iDevice, but that's not an option in my case.

Can anybody confirm me if it's even possible? And if so, what's the way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use GCDWebServer and write handlers to provide support for the [CGI protocol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Gateway_Interface). This would work on OS X but not on iOS since you can't have your app execute another tool / script. So, no this is not possible.